# resource link rel with id spring data rest

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Having following Entities and Repositories. I could'nt manage to put the id on my relationship. Thanks in advance for your help

Related artifacts from my build.gradle (using Spring Boot version `1.5.4.RELEASE`)

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
```

---

**Entities**

**Store**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
class Store {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id

    String description

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Province province
}
```

**Province**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "province")
class Province {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id

    @NotNull
    String name
}
```

---

**Repositories**

**Store**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "stores", path = "stores")
interface StoreRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Store, Long> {
}
```

**Province**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "provinces", path = "provinces")
interface ProvinceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Province, Long> {
}
```

---

**Expected Result**
I'm expecting this result, please note link on Province

```
{
 "stores": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "desc1",
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/stores/1"
      },
      "store": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/stores/1"
      },
      "province": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/stores/1/province/1" ==> Expecting the url with provinceID since its many to one
      }
    }
  }
 ]
  //Simplified for simplicity sake
}
```

**Actual Result**
Not having the Province Id in href

```
{
 "stores": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "desc1",
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/stores/1"
      },
      "store": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/stores/1"
      },
      "province": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/stores/1/province" ==> //NO ID!
      }
    }
  }
 ]
  //Simplified for simplicity sake
}
```

---

Basically im expecting

**this**

```
"province": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/stores/1/province/1" ==> Expecting the url with provinceID since its many to one
          }
```

**instead of this**

```
  "province": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/stores/1/province" //NO province ID
  }
```

---

**Edit Jun 21  at 11:54**
I've changed `FetchType.LAZY` to `EAGER` on **`Store`** due to an error when trying to do

```
"http://localhost:8080/stores/1/province/1"
```

**GOT**

```
"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
  "message": "Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer
```

Comment: The propblem could be the @ManyToOne, because the link is stored in the Province table and not Store table. But I'm honest: I've never seen this issue before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i've found two possibles ways to solve this  one with **Projections** and the other using **ResourceProcessor**. Hope this help somebody.

[Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections).

```
@Projection(name="storeProjection", types={Store.class})
interface StoreProjection {

    long getId();
    String getDescription();
    String getPhoneNumber();
    StoreStatus getStatus();

    @Value("#{target.province.id}")
    Long getProvinceId();

    @Value("#{target.province.name}")
    String getProvinceName();
}
```

`GET http://localhost:8080/stores?projection=storeProjection`

*JSON result*

```
{
  //Store data...

    "provinceId": "1"
    "provinceName": "Prov1"

 //Links,etc data
}
```

---

**`ResourceProcessor`**  in order to add a new link with desired info

```
@Configuration
class ResourcesProcessors {

    @Autowired
    EntityLinks entityLinks

    @Bean
    public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Store>> storeProcessor() {

        return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<Store>>() {
            @Override
            public Resource<Store> process(Resource<Store> resource) { //Este punto solo se agregan nuevos links

                Store store = resource.getContent()
                Link link = entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(Province.class, store.province.id);
                resource.add(link);
                return resource;
            }
        };
    }
}
```